# How can I troubleshoot this re-occuring prompt to give a mysterious app security access?

Tags: macos, security, bug, login-items

**EDIT: Found some files, not sure if deleting them will fix the issue though.  Does anybody know if I can just delete these?:**
[image]

---

For a couple months now, I've been getting this error, periodically, a few times a day, randomly. It's been happening ever since I've gotten my new Macbook (I did the thing where I connected both laptops with a USB-C and copied everything over the first time i launched the new laptop)

[image]

Never have I ever, on this laptop, or in my last laptop, installed this before, to my knowledge. I have googled the error and found nothing

This application also does not exist in `/Applications` or `~/Applications`, and there's no process that looks like this in Activity Monitor.

I also did a disk search with `sudo find / -name network` and there were 0 hits that looked like this could be it

I also checked login items in my Account preferences, and this doesn't exist either.

Even if I restart my machine, it will eventually show up again

I also do not run much on my machine.  Here are my login items, and besides that day-to-day I use Xcode, SourceTree, and Chrome.

In the past I have used Shadow App and Parallels, I'm thinking maybe one of those apps may have placed something in that was just sleeping, and then got backed up onto my new machine... but I still can't find anything.

Does anybody know how I can troubleshoot this further? it's been driving me crazy!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code instead:

```
sudo rm -r /Library/Frameworks/EveUSB.framework
```

It was coming from an old install of Shadow App as well

Comment: i think you were downvoted because your answer looks the same as my self-answer? i'm not sure. either way, i'll mark yours as correct, because you added `sudo` and `-r` :) people shouldn't be punished for going out of their way to add information

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by extensions that were installed when the [Eltima USB Networks Gate for Mac application](https://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/) was installed.

A couple of possible solutions I found:

This one from [an Eltima forum](https://forum.eltima.com/index.php?topic=126957.msg193737#msg193737) which it's recommended to run in safe mode:

```
sudo /Library/Frameworks/EveUSB.framework/Support/uninstall
```

The other is from a [Stack Overflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984690/remove-kernel-extension-which-causes-kernel-panic-after-migration-to-other-mac) that provides a script for finding and removing any Eltima USB Networks Gate for Mac extensions.

Comment: Thanks for digging those up! So I tried both, but unfortunately there is no `uninstall`... i'm going to add details into the question.  Not sure what I can do from here, if I can just delete these files?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's been a week and it hasn't shown back up, so here is the solution:

```
rm /Library/Frameworks/EveUSB.framework
```

There was no `uninstall` script, so I just removed the entire framework and the problem disappeared.  I have no idea what was trying to run this framework, from my googling it seems best guess is Shadow App (VM for gaming), which I installed a year ago, but never noticed until I updated my macOS and these security popups started showing up